# Casting Linq results does not work as expected

Tags: c#

This could be a stupid question as I'm pretty new to Linq. I've created a Linq expression that returns a list of strings. I can iterate over the result. However when I cast the result to a List it produces a run time error. See this code:

```
class Product { public string name; }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Product> p1 = new Dictionary<string, Product>();
        p1["a"] = new Product() { name = "first"} ;
        p1["b"] = new Product() { name = "second" };

        var Y = p1.Values.Select(x => x.name);
        foreach (string s in Y) { Console.WriteLine(s); }

        List<string> ls = (List<string>)p1.Values.Select(x => x.name); // this fails !?
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: List<string> ls = p1.Values.Select(x => x.name).ToList();

Comment: It's not a list but an `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want a list use `ToList`, if you want an array use `ToArray`, if you don't want to create a collection from the query leave it as it is.

Answer (score 8):

It fails because `Select` does not return a List. you need to use `ToList` to materialize your query:

```
 List<string> ls = p1.Values.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

`LINQ` methods uses *deferred execution*, it means they don't return you results until you run the query by iterating (e.g using `foreach`) or use some method to force iteration (like `ToArray` or `ToList` method).

Here are some useful readings:

- [Lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)
- [LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)
- [Deferred Execution and Lazy Evaluation in LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx)

Comment: + Extra if possible, for being the only answer to explain the full reason *why* the cast is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> ls = p1.Values.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

is usually the correct way to do this. Linq methods (e.g. Select) return IEnumerable, so you can't cast it this way. IEnumerable is a very general collection, while List is concrete. You can't safely assume that every IEnumerable is List, but you can say that every List is also IEnumerable...

In the MSDN documentation you can see, that such explicit castings fail, if the cast type isn't in fact of the same type as the target type. See this to get a better idea about casting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Or you can do it like this:

```
var results = 1.Values.Select(x => x.name);
List<string> ls = new List<string>(results);
```

by using the overload constructor that accepts IEnumerable, but `ToList()` is much more common in situations like this.

Answer (score 4):

```
p1.Values.Select(x => x.name); // this fails !?
```

Yes, it does, because `Select` does not return a `List<string>` hidden behind the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.  Use `ToList()`.

```
var ls = p1.Values.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.ToList()` extension method. It is not a list at that point, but an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Linq returns an `IEnumerable<string>` in that case which is not a `List<string>`, you can tell Linq to convert it to string by using the `.ToList()` at the end of the expression:

```
List<string> ls = p1.Values.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```